# Export custom probes graphs from offline run in JProfiler

Tags: java, export, offline, jprofiler

I'm using offline profiling in JProfiler (in a remote machine) and I was trying to export the graphs from the snapshot using the jpexport command. However, from some reason, I can't get the ones from my custom probes, even if when I use the JProfiler GUI to open the snapshot, I have access to those graphs.

Note that I'm collecting data through the Profiling API, using Java classes which implements the 'TelemetryProbe', for example. In the documentation, there is also the possiblity of using the Custom Probe Wizard, and I wonder if I have to do by this method to get what I want, after exporting the session files to the profiling machine.

For the jpexport, I tried to export the graphs from 'ProbeTelemetry', following the instructions for the custom probes, giving the ID 1 to get my first probe, with no success. I even tried 0, but still, it returned saying there was no probe with such ID.

Still, I repeat, when uploading the snapshot with the GUI, the graphs are there, so JProfiler is collecting the information, I just can't figure out how to access it.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As probe names for the export, use

```
-probeid=1
```

where n is the 1-based index of the custom probe.

Comment: I already tried that, but it doesn't work. This is how I do it and the message I get: 
jpexport snapshot.jps ProbeTelemetry -probeid="custom.1" out.html
Loading snapshot.jps
Exporting view ProbeTelemetry to out.html
The probe with probe ID "custom.1" could not be found in the snapshot.
Export failed.

Comment: I'm sorry, my answer was wrong, I've edited my answer (I checked it this time)

Comment: I tried with your new suggestion, but still, I get the same error message: The probe with probe ID "1" could not be found in the snapshot. Export failed. As a desperate measure, I even tried ranging the id from 0 to 10, but nothing. Do you know any other possibility? Thanks for trying to help me out.

Comment: Please send a snapshot to support@ej-technologies.com if possible. If it is larger than 10 MB, please ask us for FTP upload details.

Comment: It is only 246KB, so I have sent the snapshot as you said.